# Print function followed by a break function returns nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import randint
goal = randint(1,2)
guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
while (goal != guess):
    if(guess > goal):
        print('too high')
        guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
    elif(guess < goal):
        print('too low')
        guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
    elif(guess == goal):
        print('☺')
        break
```

This is my code and i dont know why the interpreter and console are returning nothing.

```
guess a number from 1 to 2. 2
too high
guess a number from 1 to 2. 1
>>>
```

I really dont know what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:Thank you all very much! This really helped. ***Thanks***

Comment: On the second `input` call, the condition `goal != guess` becomes `False` and the `while` loop exits. Move the `guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))` inside the `while` loop, before the first `if` statement and remove the call to `input` before the `while`.

Comment: Just use `while True:` instead of the pre-mature check.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop condition is exiting the loop before your `elif guess == goal` gets a chance to see the equality. Every time you provide a new input, it's always tested by `while goal != guess:` before it can reach `elif guess == goal:`.

To fix, you can either make the `while` an infinite loop:

```
while True:  # Never exit here, so final case is responsible for printing/breaking
    if guess > goal:
        print('too high')
        guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
    elif guess < goal:
        print('too low')
        guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
    else:  # No need for elif at all; for ints, not being greater or less than implies equal
        print('☺')
        break
```

or move the body of the final `elif` outside the `while` loop:

```
while goal != guess:
    if guess > goal:
        print('too high')
        guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
    elif guess < goal:
        print('too low')
        guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
print('☺')  # If we got here, goal must be equal to guess
```

In both cases, I fixed up the style a bit to match PEP8 (you don't need parentheses are conditional tests for `while`/`if` in Python).

Really, to minimize code duplication, you'd want to move the `input` to the top of the loop, and only break at the bottom, making your code something like:

```
goal = randint(1,2)
while True:
    guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
    if guess > goal:
        print('too high')
    elif guess < goal:
        print('too low')
    else:
        print('☺')
        break
```

or with Python 3.8+'s [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) to allow setting and testing in the conditional, you could make it a titch more concise (though possibly more obscure) with:

```
goal = randint(1,2)
while goal != (guess := int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))):
    if guess > goal:
        print('too high')
    else:
        print('too low')
print('☺')  # If we got here, goal must be equal to guess
```

Comment: How can i move the elif? wouldnt that creata an syntax error?

Comment: @SzymonBartnicki: Just updated with example code. To be clear, I said to move the *body* of the `elif`, not the `elif` itself (you'd delete the `elif` line itself, as well as the `break` that's no longer inside a loop).

Answer (score 0):

Place the guess at the top of the loop rather than in each condition. This allows you to know which line is getting prited, it's easy to update, and you're not repeating code.

```
low, high = 1, 2
goal = randint(low, high)
while True:
    guess = int(input(f'guess a number from {low} to {high}: '))

    if(guess > goal):
        print('too high')
    elif(guess < goal):
        print('too low')
    elif(guess == goal):
        print('Success!')
        break
```

Comment: The initial comparison of an integer to `None` is a bit iffy, though. A loop without an explicit condition would be better, especially since you are making an equivalent check in the body of the loop.

Comment: Good point. There really isn't a need to have that if we use `break` to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

So I will try to form my answer so you can follow along.

```
while (goal != guess):
```

Is the culprit. This gets run on every loop. So the moment it is true it will break out of the loop without checking that final statement to print the smiley face. So one solution might be to do the following:

```
from random import randint
goal = randint(1,2)
guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
guessed = False
while not guessed:
    if(guess > goal):
        print('too high')
        guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
    elif(guess < goal):
        print('too low')
        guess = int(input('guess a number from 1 to 2'))
    elif(guess == goal):
        print('☺')
        guessed = True
```

Hope this helps you out.